# GWT permutation count

Tags: gwt, localization, permutation

When I do

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie9,gecko1_8,safari,opera" />
```

the compiler does **4 permutations**;

But adding :

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie9,gecko1_8,safari,opera" />

<extend-property name="locale" values="nl" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="en" />

<collapse-property name="locale" values="en*" />
<collapse-property name="locale" values="nl*" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />
```

I see **48 permutations**. But I would **expect 4 * 2 = 8** permutations.

What are the 48 permutations and/or is there a way to instruct the compiler to show what the permutations represent during the compilation process ?

I also have this in my module `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales" />`

****UPDATE**** : This change gives **56 permutations**

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="nl_NL" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="nl_BE" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_GB" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en_GB" />
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie9,gecko1_8,safari,opera" />
```

It still is not clear to how the compiler gets to this number ?

Comment: One nit: you should have `<set-property name="locale" value="en,nl"/>` or you'll still have the `default` locale even though you'll never use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This comment from Thomas revealed the solution :

> you should have `<set-property name="locale" value="en,nl"/>` or you'll
>   still have the default locale even though you'll never use it.

So modified to :

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="nl_NL" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="nl_BE" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_GB" />
<set-property name="locale" value="en_GB,nl_NL,nl_BE"/>
<!-- <collapse-property name="locale" values="en*" /> <collapse-property 
    name="locale" values="nl*" /> -->
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en_GB" />
```

=> **12 permutations**, as expected from **4 (browsers) * 3 (lang/country) = 12 permutations**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you ran in to this issue.

It seems its producing permutations for all countries(?).

> For cases where the translated values are the same, but you still want country-specific details, you can use runtime locales to reduce the number of compiled permutations, but still get country-specific details like the default currency, number/date formatting rules, etc.

As an example, you might have one set of translations for all of Spanish as spoken in Latin America (es_419), yet allow users to choose a country-specific locale such as Argentinian Spanish (es_AR).

[**Read Runtime LocaleSpecifying**](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale#LocaleSpecifying)

Comment: that is what should be prevented by adding the collapse property statements like <collapse-property name="locale" values="en*" /> , no ?

Comment: Collapse properties doesn't reduce the number of permutations, it reduces the number of output files, by collapsing several permutations into the same output script.

Comment: reducing the number of lang/countries even further results in even more (56!) permutations, see updated question. Still puzzled on how the compiler calculates the number of permutations. I had only 4 before adding country/lang.